# postgres: do I really need to use Collate and Ctype when restoring database?

Tags: postgresql, restore, collation, locales

Need to import in Linux a Windows postgres exported database.
In windows it's listed as follows:

```
    Name     |  Owner   | Encoding |      Collate       |       Ctype        |   Access privileges
-------------+----------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------------
   the_db    | postgres | UTF8     | Hebrew_Israel.1255 | Hebrew_Israel.1255 |
```

Do I really need to create the database using the same collate and ctype before restoring?
I already tested, and I can import just by creating a new database which will make it using its defaults:

```
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 the_db    | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
```

- Restoring was successful. Hoever, I am afraid because of the application, not to cause any errors when interacting with the db later.
- What are your consideration gentleman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main consideration is that if you use `ORDER BY` with a column of a string data type, the result will be sorted according to the database collation unless you specify an explicit `COLLATE` clause for the column definition or with the `ORDER BY`. If your users expect the results sorted according to Hebrew sorting rules, they might be unhappy.

To get a Hebrew collation on Unix, use the locale `he_IL.utf8`.

Comment: I've tried to create it using "create database test WITH OWNER "postgres" ENCODING 'UTF8' LC_COLLATE = 'Hebrew_Israel.1255' LC_CTYPE = 'Hebrew_Israel.1255';" however I end up with "ERROR:  invalid locale name: "Hebrew_Israel.1255"". Not really sure how to solve it...and I googled it for a while ..

Comment: You could try `he_IL.utf8`, as noted in my extended answer.

Comment: indeed "create database the_db with template=template0 encoding='utf8' lc_collate='he_IL.utf8' lc_ctype='he_IL.utf8' owner=postgres;" makes it work. Hebrew_Israel.1255 is the collation for windows. thanks!